# mysql results equally distributed into groups within a php output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql     = "select pid from Athletes order by RAND()";
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$total   = mysql_num_rows($results);
```

I need to equally distribute the results across varied totals.
The maximum number in each group is 6 and the minimum being 4.
I am trying to make is scale beyond 2 groups of athletes.
Teams need to be equally distributed a much as possible.

Examples:

```
Total = 7 will have 2 groups with one having 4 and the other with 3.
Total = 17 will have 2 groups of 6 and one of 5.
Total = 25 will be 5 groups of 5.
Total = 26 will have 1 group of 6 and 4 groups of 5.
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you determine when you want a 4-group or a 6-group?

Comment: (1) `order by RAND()` can murder performance.  If you want a random order, consider `select pid, RAND() sort_order from Athletes order by sort_order`.  (2) `mysql_query` is old and crusty and deprecated.  Look into migrating to mysqli (which, in the worst case, very closely matches the ext/mysql API).

Comment: you say minimum is 4 and then you split 7 into 4 and 3 how is that

Comment: `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: @cHao Why is the one bad for performance and not the other? They do the exact same thing? Is the `ORDER BY ...` part evaluated more?

Comment: The number of groups would be determined by the total number of Athletes.  The goal is to randomly assign them a position on a team that is between 4-6 athletes.  This could be 400-500 athletes participating in this event and as little as 4.

Comment: @Rudie:  Oops.  Never mind that part.  :P  It'd be possible to evaluate the `rand()` each time rows are compared and make things really awkward, but MySQL apparently doesn't do that.  `order by rand() is still a huge drain with decent size tables on a busy server, but for a few hundred rows, the difference won't matter much.

Comment: This table will not be heavily used, I agree that the rand() can create a hit to the DB but with the number of times this query will be run it won't matter.  I don't see any more than 600 entries and will be run 2x over a 4 day event.  My challenge is trying to evenly distribute the Athletes over several squads without having to develop a bunch of if, else statements.  Was hoping someone might have a clean way to run this.